# [UITableViewCell menuImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bb1e5e0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created a separate `UITableViewCell` and designed it using `.xib` file and it looks like
[image]

My header file for `UITableViewCell` looks like

```
@interface MenuTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *menuImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *menuLabel;
@end
```

and both properties are connected
[image]
[image]
I tried to use it in my `MenuViewController` as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.menuImage.image = [self getImageNameForRow:indexPath.row];
    cell.menuLabel.text = self.features[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

and

```
- (UIImage *)getImageNameForRow:(NSInteger)row {
    if (row == 0) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Transaction"];
    }
    if (row == 1) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Summary"];
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Budget"];
}
```

when I run my application, it crashes and shows the following on log

```
2014-08-30 14:51:54.387 pennyapp-ios[37988:70b] -[UITableViewCell menuImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bb1e5e0
2014-08-30 14:51:54.389 pennyapp-ios[37988:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell menuImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bb1e5e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023c6495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010212599e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010245765d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b7d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b7938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   pennyapp-ios                        0x00000001000044ed -[MenuTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 141
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100904f8a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001008ead5b -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2337
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001008fc721 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100890993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fbc802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fb1369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fb11ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104f24fb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104f26030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100848e25 _afterCACommitHandler + 128
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102391dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102391d37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102371522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102370d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001036e3f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000100830e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    22  pennyapp-ios                        0x0000000100001353 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001033655fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am very new to `iOS` and can't understand the error message, can some one please help me knowing what am In doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you use proper CellIdentifier? Didn't you forget to specify it in IB for your MenuTableViewCell by chance?

Comment: The error clearly shows that `dequeue...` returns an instance of `UITableViewCell`, not `MenuTableViewCell`. Can you show us the portion of your code where you **register** your cell type in the table view?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637434/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-when-using-custom-table-cell

Comment: The problem is that you did not construct a MenuTabelViewCell, but rather a UITableViewCell.  There are several different ways you could have screwed this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 2 problems.

1. I was registering `UITableViewCell` instead of `MenuTableViewCell`
2. I was not registering the `nib` file I had

After making the change as following things, started to work again.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MenuTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Thank you for all your answers, they helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Declare an imgearray in interface,then add your array of images,next cellforatindexpath add code for UIImageView
yourcellname.yourimagename.image=[UIImage imagenamed:[yourimagearray objectAtIndexPath.row]];